# How to include a programming language source code file in a plain TeX document?

Tags: plain-tex, sourcecode

I have some Java and C source codes and I want to include them in my `.tex` document. I can't simply copy and paste them into my document: In fact, doing this way, the code won't appear with the right spacings and indentations.  I'd like that the source code does appear the same way it looks when opened in any text editor.

Is there a simple way to do it? Is there a macro (for the plain format) that takes care of that automatically?

Comment: take a look at [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings)

Comment: @SeanAllred Isn't ``listings`` a LaTeX package?  I asked for a plain TeX macro...

Comment: @Matteo Plain users tend not to be big on 'automatic'. Moreover, there might be specific requirements here you've not mentioned: verbatim is easy enough to set up, verbatim input a little more tricky, highlighting/line selection/... much more so. Could you give us a bit more detail about your requirements?

Comment: @Matteo Whoops; I read too quickly. Retracted :) That said, I'd re-iterate what Joseph says above: these aren't trivial problems to solve by any stretch of the imagination.  Depending on your situation, you might just want to use LaTeX / ConTeXt.

Comment: @JosephWright  Let's simplify the problem.  When you write on a text editor you can obtain larger spacings by putting together more space characters or by using the tab character; but in TeX more spaces are regarded as only one.  So I'm looking for a way to include a text file so that its appearance is similar to when I open it in a text editor.  Suppose my text file is named "source.c". Then the macro I'm looking for should work like this way:  ``\textinclusion\input source.c \endtextinclusion``

Comment: @JosephWright I've just found the ``\listing`` command of ``eplain`` that do such a thing

Comment: @Matteo Please post a self-answer :-) It would also be good if you'd tighten up the question a little (I guess to include criteria such as '(i) obey spaces, (ii) obey lines, (iii) treat special chars as normal text, (iv) use a monospaced font' or something similar.

Comment: looks like you've found an answer using `eplain`.  i was going to suggest that the "plain" version of the tugboat macros (`tugboat.sty`, should be in the `tex/plain/tugboat-plain` area of a full tex live distribution) contains a nice implementation of verbatim that takes into account spaces at the beginnings of lines, which (if i remember correctly) knuth's original in the texbook ignores.

Comment: You could also perhaps read section "3. Verbatim Listing" in Appendix D of the TeXBook, which explains exactly what you need to do in plain TeX to include files verbatim; or if you are more adventurous look up "programs, for computers" in the index and see how you can pretty-print source code in plain TeX.

Answer (score 7):

I've found the solution in the `eplain` format (which I actually use as an extension of Knuth's `plain`, and in addition to `amstex` and `epsf`). In `eplain` there is a macro called `\listing` that takes as argument the text file you want to include in your document.

Suppose we have a text file called `Main.c`.  Then if you use the command `\listing{Main.c}`, TeX reads the file `Main.c` and puts it in your document, making it appear as it appears when you open it in a text editor. The text file is typeset using the Computer Modern 10pt typewriter font, but you can simply change this behaviour (for more information have a look at `eplain` documentation).